# Trying to clarify a conceptual gap regarding shifting and rotation of axis

Tags: geometry, contest-math, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

> Find the new equation of the curve $4(x-2y+1)^2+9(2x+y+2)^2=25$ if the lines $2x+y+2=0$ and $x-2y+1=0$ are taken as the new $x$ and $y$-axis respectively.

The given lines are perpendicular, so, I thought maybe $2x+y+2$ can be replaced as $x$ and $x-2y+1$ can be replaced as $y$. So, maybe the answer would be $4x^2+9y^2=25$

But the answer given is $4x^2+9y^2=5$

Seems like they replaced $\frac{2x+y+2}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}}$ as $x$, i.e. seems like they replaced perpendicular distances with $x$ and $y$, but why?

I am aware of shifting of origin and rotation of axis. And in this question both concepts seem to be applied.

Also, rotation of axis also involves $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$ etc, perhaps that's not needed here, given the staight forward answer.

Also, the fact that the given curve is ellipse has any bearing on the approach?

This question is present on [infinity learn website](https://infinitylearn.com/surge/question/mathematics/the-new-equation-of-the-curve4x-2y1292xy2225if-t/)

Comment: On rewriting the ellipse equation you can substitute x-2y+1 as Y and 2x+y+2 as X like you did, to get $4x^2$+$9y^2$=5, perhaps there maybe an extra factor involved.

Comment: If you want to keep the metric properties, you have to have a unit vector along your new axes, as you have seen.

Comment: You must set $X=(ax + by + c)/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ if you want all lengths to be preserved in the change of axes.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thanks but I am not sure why lengths won't be preserved if we are not dividing by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland thanks I am also able to feel that there should be a unit vector but I am not able to put a reason to it.

Comment: Compute $(X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-Y_2)^2$ with your new coordinates and check by yourself this is not the same as $(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a change of variables, so that the new axes are aligned with two perpendicular lines with equations
$$
ax+by+c=0,\quad
a'x+b'y+c'=0.
$$
If you want lengths to be the same with the new coordinates $(X,Y)$, then you must choose them as follows (or swapping $X$ with $Y$):
$$
X={ax+by+c\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\quad
Y={a'x+b'y+c'\over\sqrt{a'^2+b'^2}}.
\tag1
$$
PROOF.
Note first of all that, as those two lines are perpendicular,
then $aa'+bb'=0$, that is:
$$
{a'\over b}=-{b'\over a}=k.
$$
We can then substitute $a'=kb$ and $b'=-ka$ in equation $(1)$
obtaining:
$$
X={ax+by+c\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\quad
Y={bx-ay+c'/k\over\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.
\tag1
$$
Take now any two points expressed by $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ in the old coordinates. Their squared distance, computed with the new coordinates, is:
$$
d^2=(X_1-X_2)^2+(Y_1-Y_2)^2=
{(ax_1+by_1-ax_2-by_2)^2\over{a^2+b^2}}+
{(bx_1-ay_1-bx_2+ay_2)^2\over{a^2+b^2}}
$$
that is:
$$
\begin{align}
d^2 & =
{a^2(x_1-x_2)^2+b^2(y_1-y_2)^2+2ab(x_1-x_2)(y_1-y_2)\over{a^2+b^2}}\\
&+{b^2(x_1-x_2)^2+a^2(y_1-y_2)^2-2ab(x_1-x_2)(y_1-y_2)\over{a^2+b^2}}\\
&=(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2.
\end{align}
$$
But the last expression is the squared distance computed with the old coordinates: that completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suspect that might be a typo of your book. Nevertheless, you can always take the new axis and scale it, for example, let

$kx'=2x+y+2$ and $ky'=x-2y+1$

now you get

$4k^2x'^2+9k^2y'^2=25$

you can take different $k$ and the curve will be scaled.

Comment: Hi. I have added one link in my post

Comment: As per your answer, all the options given in that link should be correct?

Comment: all answers are incorrect, it seems they swap x' and y'

Comment: Hmm.. I seem to have made the same mistake. Interestingly, I had not made this mistake the first time I attempted this question.

Comment: no worries, as long as you know the idea behind this problem, then it is done :)

Answer (score 1):

The expanded equation is $40x^2+20xy+25y^2+80x+20y+15=0.$ Treat this to the translate and rotate standard matrix treatment which gives a center that we translate to the origin and a rotation matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix}\cos{\theta}&-\sin{\theta}\\\sin{\theta}&\cos{\theta}\end{pmatrix}$ for one $\theta \in (-180^\circ,180^\circ].$

I suspect the ones making the exercise  want you to make sure yours is a determinant $1$ one coming from such a cosine/sine rotation.

> This forces the order `P=matrix([1/sqrt(5),-2/sqrt(5)],[2/sqrt(5),1/sqrt(5)])` of the normalized eigenvectors as columns in the rotation matrix and `4*x'^2+9*y'^2=5.` The other order would switch $x$ and $y.$

> Or `4*((x+1)-2*y)^2/5+9*(2*(x+1)+y)^2/5=5` going back again through the translation from `(-1,0)` and rotation by `63.43... degrees`.